# is there a way or example to create abstract sytanx tree with ply and ast?

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree, transpiler, ply

İ am currently working on a transpiler in python.I am planing to use ply ast and astor to create the program. but i can't really find a good example to create my syntax tree with ply and ast modules.
is there an example or document about this that explains clearly ?
thank you.

Comment: Did you try the Python docs? https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: A transpiler from what to what? Ast (and astor) are used to work with Python's own ASTs; they are not general-purpose AST libraries, whatever that might be, and the details of the AST changes with every new Python version. What did you intend to use them for?

Comment: https://github.com/pablasso/chelodina I am trying to use it as this project but it is not detailed and not clear how i can write new codes on it. I know it changes but my project will not change therefore, using the same versions will not be a problem for the future. ıf you have any other idea about transpilers i will be happy to hear. thank you.